# How to get specific NPCs to move in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I know how to get a NPC to move in but what is the quickest way to get the one you want? Also, how long does it take for them to move in?

Comment: Have you looked at the [NPC requirements](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/NPC#Town_NPCs) on the wiki?

Comment: I'm not sure, but do we have anything against questions that show zero research effort?

Comment: @user1337 Downvotes?

Comment: @MikeKellogg Honestly, I can't remember the last time I downvoted. Don't want to part with those 2 reputation points or whatever there is.

Comment: @user1337 It's -1 reputation to downvote answers, doesn't cost anything to downvote questions.

Comment: Well now it feels a lot better to click those arrows. Thanks for the headsup.

Answer (score 2):

In Terraria, all of the NPCs are set in order so whenever you build a room with the required needs, the first NPC will move in and then the next will move in once you build more rooms. It doesn't take too long but it will take a few minutes for the NPC to spawn and move in so it gives you some extra time to do stuff while you are waiting.